# jQuery Mobile getJSON get data with var

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

For example, I have a json file with cars from Ford and Volkswagen. Now I have a var where 'ford' or 'volkswagen' is stored. How can I use this var in combination with the data selection.

```
$.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.ford, function(i, item) {
        //do something      
    });
});


$.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.volkswagen, function(i, item) {
        //do something      
    });
});
```

I mean something like

```
var brand = 'ford';
data.+brand
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access that item in the object by using something like:

```
var brand = 'ford';
data[brand];
```

You can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets) on dot and square bracket notation.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
var brand = 'ford';
$.each(data[brand], function(i, item) {....
```

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
 var brand = 'ford';
    $.getJSON('file.json', function(data) {
      $.each(data[brand], function(i, item) {
        //do something      
      });
    });
```